# How to add `toggleSidebar` NSToolbarItem in Catalyst?

Tags: swift, uikit, nstoolbar, mac-catalyst

In my app, I added a `toggleSidebar` item to the `NSToolbar`.

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
extension SceneDelegate: NSToolbarDelegate {
    func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [NSToolbarItem.Identifier.toggleSidebar, NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace, AddRestaurantButtonToolbarIdentifier]
    }
}
#endif
```

However, when I compile my app to Catalyst, the button is disabled. Does anybody know what else I need to do to hook it up?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for `.toggleSidebar`/`NSToolbarToggleSidebarItemIdentifier` you will see:

> The standard toolbar item identifier for a sidebar. It sends toggleSidebar: to firstResponder.

Adding that method to your view controller will enable the button in the toolbar:

Swift:

```swift
@objc func toggleSidebar(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

Objective-C:

```c
- (void)toggleSidebar:(id)sender {
}
```

Your implementation will need to do whatever you want to do when the user taps the button in the toolbar.

Normally, under a real macOS app using an `NSSplitViewController`, this method is handled automatically by the split view controller and you don't need to add your own implementation of `toggleSidebar:`.

Comment: @user4992124 Did this answer your question?

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more on how to make the button actually work, I mean actually show/hide the side bar in a UISplitViewController. And how to make the button stay enabled no matter what the first responder is.

Answer (score 1):

The target needs changed to `self`, this is shown in this [Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/touch_bar/integrating_a_toolbar_and_touch_bar_into_your_app?language=objc) where it is done for the print item but can easily be changed to the toggle split item as I did after the comment.

```
/** This is an optional delegate function, called when a new item is about to be added to the toolbar.
    This is a good spot to set up initial state information for toolbar items, particularly items
    that you don't directly control yourself (like with NSToolbarPrintItemIdentifier).
    The notification's object is the toolbar, and the "item" key in the userInfo is the toolbar item
    being added.
 */
func toolbarWillAddItem(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    if let addedItem = userInfo["item"] as? NSToolbarItem {
        let itemIdentifier = addedItem.itemIdentifier
        if itemIdentifier == .print {
            addedItem.toolTip = NSLocalizedString("print string", comment: "")
            addedItem.target = self
        }
        // added code
        else if itemIdentifier == .toggleSidebar {
            addedItem.target = self
        }
    }
}
```

And then add the action to the scene delegate by adding the Swift equivalent of this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleSidebar:(id)sender{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = (splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode != UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden ? UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden : UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When configuring your `UISplitViewController`, set the `primaryBackgroundStyle` to `.sidebar`

```
let splitVC: UISplitViewController = //your application's split view controller
splitVC.primaryBackgroundStyle = .sidebar
```

This will enable your `NSToolbarItem` with the system identifier `.toggleSidebar` and it will work automatically with the `UISplitViewController` in Mac Catalyst without setting any target / action code.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is mainly converting @malhal's answer to the latest Swift version**

1. You will need to return `[.toggleSidebar]` in `toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers`.
2. In `toolbarWillAddItem` you will write the following (just like the previous answer suggested):

```swift
  func toolbarWillAddItem(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    if let addedItem = userInfo["item"] as? NSToolbarItem {
      let itemIdentifier = addedItem.itemIdentifier
      if itemIdentifier == .toggleSidebar {
        addedItem.target = self
        addedItem.action = #selector(toggleSidebar)
      }
    }
  }
```

3. Finally, you will add your `toggleSidebar` method.

```
  @objc func toggleSidebar() {
    let splitController = self.window?.rootViewController as? MainSplitController
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
      splitController?.preferredDisplayMode = (splitController?.preferredDisplayMode != .primaryHidden ? .primaryHidden : .allVisible)
    }
  }
```

---

A few resources that might help:

1. [Integrating a Toolbar and Touch Bar into Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/touch_bar/integrating_a_toolbar_and_touch_bar_into_your_app)
2. [Mac Catalyst: Adding a Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/mac-catalyst/adding-a-toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use the `toggleSidebar` toolbar item is to set `primaryBackgroundStyle` to `.sidebar`, as answered by [@Craig Scrogie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933390/656176).
That has the side effect of enabling the toolbar item and hiding/showing the sidebar.

If you don't want to use the `.sidebar` background style, you have to implement toggling the sidebar and validating the toolbar item in methods on a class in your responder chain. I put these in a subclass of `UISplitViewController`.

```swift
@objc func toggleSidebar(_ sender: Any?) {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.preferredDisplayMode =
      (self.displayMode == .secondaryOnly) ?
        .oneBesideSecondary : .secondaryOnly
  })
}

@objc func validateToolbarItem(_ item: NSToolbarItem)
    -> Bool {
  if item.action == #selector(toggleSidebar) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```